# Scrolling by hiding scroller in GtkScrolledWindow

Tags: gtk

I have a gtkscrolledwindow object which sets to GTK_POLICY_NEVER for both horizontal

and vertical scrollbar. I have placed one button on each side of it. My requirement is

when i click left button all the elements should scroll left and vice versa for right

button. So, on what ways this requirement can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using Adjustment associated with the scrolledwindow. get the adjustment object from scrolledwindow and set the new value for the adjustment then scrolling effect will come into effect. within the scrolled window you can add any number of widgets....